# Display Reactive form elements concurrently real-time in Angular

Tags: forms, angular, reactive, angular-forms

I am having problem figuring out how to display the form elements/values concurrently as they are being entered/inputted by the user. I wish to display them while the user is still typing and has not yet pressed the submit button.

The json pipes have allowed me to display all the elements but I cannot figure out how to display a singular element in the HTML code.

```
    {{commentForm.value | json}}
```

I can access all the elements using the above JSON pipe but want to access singular elements.

Sample Angular Reactive Form code below.

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <p>
            <md-input-container class="full-width" dividerColor="{{formErrors.author ? 'warn': 'primary'}}" >
                <input mdInput formControlName="author" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>

                <md-hint>
                    <span [hidden] = "!(formErrors.author)">
                        {{formErrors.author}}
                    </span>
                </md-hint>

            </md-input-container> 
            <md-input-container class="full-width" dividerColor="{{formErrors.rating ? 'warn': 'primary'}}" >
                <input mdInput formControlName="rating" placeholder="Rating" type="number" pattern="[0-5]*" required>
                <md-hint>
                    <span [hidden] = "!(formErrors.rating)">
                        {{formErrors.rating}}
                    </span>
                </md-hint>
            </md-input-container> 
            <md-input-container class="full-width" dividerColor="{{formErrors.comment ? 'warn': 'primary'}}" >
                <input mdInput formControlName="comment" placeholder="Your Comment" type="text" required>
                <md-hint>
                    <span [hidden] = "!(formErrors.comment)">
                        {{formErrors.comment}}
                    </span>
                </md-hint>
            </md-input-container>
        </p>
         <button type="submit" md-button class="background-primary text-floral-white" [disabled]="commentForm.invalid">Submit</button>            
    </form>
```

I wish to display the author, rating and the comments individually. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: can you add a plunkr working??

Comment: Apologies. I saw this late. And I am sorry, I am having trouble exporting the modules and components in Plunkr. Still new to this and Angular. But you can check out the answer stojevskimilan posted below. It works!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`FormGroup` is a object that contains `value` that is a object that contains your `formControl` properties

To access invidiual values

`<p>{{commentForm.value.author}}</p>`

`<p>{{commentForm.value.rating}}</p>`

`<p>{{commentForm.value.comment}}</p>`

Comment: Hey! This works. Thankyou. Such a straightforward solution.

Comment: Glad to help :)